# Corner Radius lost after loading an image using ALCameraViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

At first it looks like this

[image: Screen Shot]

After I pick a photo to load from the library using ALCameraViewController, it looks like this

[image: Screen Shot]

**Here is the code I use**

```
photo.layer.borderWidth = 1
photo.layer.masksToBounds = true
photo.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
photo.layer.cornerRadius = photo.frame.height/2
photo.clipsToBounds = true
```

How can I prevent it to loose corner radius?

[Link to ALCameraViewController](https://github.com/AlexLittlejohn/ALCameraViewController)

Comment: You might want to note what `photo` is and where you're calling the code (`viewDidLoad`, etc.). Is it a `UIImageView` or some proprietary class from the framework you're using? You could chuck your code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` after updating the image.

Comment: I found this issue with image view, If your image pixel/quality is low, that time corner radius is not working. Just check with good quality image, Its gonna work.

Comment: @AbdulHoqueNuri tried with very good quality image. didnt work

Comment: @Adrian tried your suggestion but didn't work